# Duplicate verbiage is self-contradictory

Tags: feature-request

Does this really make any sense? The OP *is* asking a new question.

> marked as duplicate by ... Feb 11 at 16:52
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new
>   question.

Comment: I agree, it's not great wording.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166525/duplicate-explanation-should-encourage-improvement-of-original This may have already been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Given the timing, you are likely referring to [What to do with a not well organized application? [duplicate]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101391/what-to-do-with-a-not-well-organized-application)

The question being asked by the OP is summarized as "I've just inherited a huge load of code that is of questionable quality and I don't know what to do with it.  Its fragile and 'like walking in a field with land mines!' What should I do?"

This question, is essentially the same as the question [I've inherited 200K lines of spaghetti code — what now?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155488/ive-inherited-200k-lines-of-spaghetti-code-what-now) which asks "What would you include in your list of the most effective strategies to help straighten out the spaghetti (and prevent it in the future)?"

These two questions ask the same thing.  Thus, "This question has been asked before and already has an answer" is correct - it has been asked before (in a slightly different form) and has already been answered.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was not asking whether the question was a duplicate. I was questioning the verbiage of the "marked as duplicate..." boilerplate which says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." Which is exactly what the OP did and is now being criticized for it.

Comment: The question that was duped was asked about two years ago.  If the poster thinks that they are different questions, then flag it for mod attention or bring it up here.  Closing as a duplicate is not criticism, but rather signposts or others to find another answer. Of note dupe question is older than the one it is duped to, but that is because the 200k question is the one we try to direct people to.